# Merging array values of arbitrary keys with jsonnet

Tags: jsonnet

I have a list of configuration files in a jsonnet document `main.jsonnet`, like this:

```
local configFiles = [
  import "file1.jsonnet",
  import "file2.jsonnet",
  import "file3.jsonnet",
];

{
# ...something goes here...
}
```

The imported files contain arbitrary sets of keys (that is, we do not know the complete list of keys in advance). For this example, `file1.jsonnet` looks like:

```
{
  names: ["alice", "bob"],
  colors: ["red"],
}
```

`file2.jsonnet` looks like:

```
{
  names: ['mallory'],
  animals: ['cow'],
}
```

And `file3.jsonnet` looks like:

```
{
  names: ['angus'],
  colors: ['brown'],
  animals: ['horse'],
  size: ['medium'],
}
```

I want to replace `# ...something goes here...` with appropriate code to generate:

```
{
  names: ["alice", "bob", "mallory", "angus"],
  colors: ["red", "brown"],
  animals: ["cow", "horse"],
  size: ["medium"],
}
```

This would be easy with a simple iterative solution; in Python I might write something like:

```
import _jsonnet as jsonnet
import json

merged = {}
fileNames = ["file1.jsonnet", "file2.jsonnet", "file3.jsonnet"]
configFiles = [json.loads(jsonnet.evaluate_file(fn)) for fn in fileNames]

for configFile in configFiles:
    for k, v in configFile.items():
        merged[k] = merged.get(k, []) + v

print(json.dumps(merged, indent=2))
```

The logic seems simple, but the only iterators available in jsonnet are array and object comprehensions which seems trickier. I tried this:

```
{
    [k]: if self[k] then self[k] + configFile[k] else configFile[k]
    for configFile in configFiles
    for k in std.objectFields(configFile)
}
```

But that results in:

```
RUNTIME ERROR: duplicate field name: "names"
        main.jsonnet:(7:1)-(11:2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very useful std function to overcome the `[keyName]` duplicate issue is [std.foldl](https://jsonnet.org/ref/stdlib.html#std.foldl).

Below example implements merging the arrays with it, for the sake of simplicity I've embedded the `configFiles` in the same src (i.e. no `import` which would achieve the same in this case).

### source: foo.jsonnet

```jsonnet
local f1 = {
  names: ['alice', 'bob'],
  colors: ['red'],
};
local f2 = {
  names: ['mallory'],
  animals: ['cow'],
};
local f3 = {
  names: ['angus'],
  colors: ['brown'],
  animals: ['horse'],
  size: ['medium'],
};
local configFiles = [f1, f2, f3];

// Use std.foldl() which will call the function() one for each element in the array,
// thus somehow "avoiding" the `[keyName]` duplicate issue
std.foldl(
  function(acc, x) acc {
    [kv.key]+: kv.value
    for kv in std.objectKeysValues(x)
  },
  configFiles,
  {}
)
```

### output

```shell
$ jsonnet foo.jsonnet
{
   "animals": [
      "cow",
      "horse"
   ],
   "colors": [
      "red",
      "brown"
   ],
   "names": [
      "alice",
      "bob",
      "mallory",
      "angus"
   ],
   "size": [
      "medium"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. I had come up with a `foldl` based solution, but your function expression is much cleaner than what I was using.